# What is $Z(\mathbb{Z}_{p} \rtimes_{\phi} \mathbb{Z}_{q})$ if $\phi$ is non-trivial and $p$ and $q$ are primes such that $q \equiv 1(\text{mod} \ p)$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism, semidirect-product

Let $p$ and $q$ be prime numbers such that $q \equiv 1(\text{mod} \  p)$. It is [known](https://drexel28.wordpress.com/2011/04/19/groups-of-order-pq-pt-ii/) that a group of order $p \cdot q$ is either isomorphic to $$\mathbb{Z}_{p} \times \mathbb{Z}_{q} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{pq}$$ or $$\mathbb{Z}_{q} \rtimes_{\phi} \mathbb{Z}_{p}$$ where $$\phi\colon \mathbb{Z}_{p} \to \text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_{q})$$ is a non-trivial morphism. We remark that $\mathbb{Z}_{q} \rtimes_{\phi} \mathbb{Z}_{p}$ is non-abelian.

So, it is natural to ask: given a non-abelian group $G$ of order $p \cdot q$ such that $q \equiv 1(\text{mod} \ p)$, what is the center of $G$?

Using the [class equation](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Class_equation_of_a_group_action), it is easily seen that a group of prime power order has a non-trivial center.  Can the class equation be used to show that a group of the form $\mathbb{Z}_{q} \rtimes_{\phi} \mathbb{Z}_{p}$ has a non-trivial center?

Comment: The center is trivial. Otherwise, the center would have prime index, and the quotient $G/Z(G)$ would be cyclic, which is impossible in a non-abelian group.

Comment: @verret Yes, that is correct.  Thank you for your response.